# How to change PHP's eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, email, pcre, posix-ere

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

I need help, below is a small VERY basic regex to somewhat validate an email, I do realize it does not work the greatest but for my needs it is ok for now.

It currently uses PHP's **eregi function** which php.net says is now a depreciated function and I should use **preg_match** instead,  simply replacing erei with preg_match does not work, can someone show me how to make it work?

```
function validate_email($email) {
    if (!eregi("^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$", $email)) {
        echo 'bad email';
    } else {
        echo 'good email';
    }
}
function validate_email($email) {
    if (!preg_match("^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$", $email)) {
        echo 'bad email';
    } else {
        echo 'good email';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you should not use this regex to validate e-mail; it is severely outdated.

Comment: @Piskvor I agree, this question is nearly 5 years old too =) you should post an updated answer if you like and I can always change the "selected" answer to the best approach

Comment: It's IMHO outside of the scope of the ereg/preg issue; commenting seems sufficient to me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Perl-style regex patterns always need to be delimited. The very first character in the string is considered the delimiter, so something like this:

```
function validate_email($email) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", $email)) {
        echo 'bad email';
    } else {
        echo 'good email';
    }
}
```

The reason your initial attempt didn't work is because it was trying to use `^` as the delimiter character but (obviously) found no matching `^` for the end of the regex.

Comment: Thanks, I just found php's FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, it seems like it might be the best way to go but I cannot find much information on it

Comment: @jasondavis, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` would definitely be a better choice. E-mails are **complicated**.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to change three things

1. need to add pattern delimiters (can be any character, but most commonly a forward slash)
2. [[:alnum:]] will need to be replaced with the PCRE equivalent
3. The "i" in "eregi" means case-insensitive, which PCRE does with a flag, specifically the `i` flag.

Otherwise, the rest looks PCRE compatible (yes, that's kind of redundant =P)

```
"/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i"
```

Comment: PHP's PCRE includes things like [:alnum:] as options.