# php ereg deprecation

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

I've tried to convert but I keep failing.

My ereg: `if (!ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,16}$",$username)) {`

is wrong because it is out of date. How do I switch it to `preg_match`?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `ereg` with `preg_match`? You need to tell us _what_ you've tried, instead of "I've tried to convert...".

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_02.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374881/how-to-change-phps-eregi-to-preg-match http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,16}$/",$username)) { /* .. */ }
```

Note the delimiters `/`.

Comment: Thank you. I get what I did wrong.