# php register script not validating email

Tags: php, validation, email

I have a register script and i want to validate that people have typed in their email correctly, but this doesnt seem to work? any ideass?

```
if ($_POST){
$email=stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$valid=eregi('^([0-9a-z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-z]+@([-0-9a-z]+[.])+[a-z]{2,6}$',$email);
if (!$email && !$valid){
    $_SESSION['error'] = "I'm sorry but the email you specified is not valid.     Please enter a valid email";
    unset($email);
    header("Location: register.php");
    exit;

}
    }
```

Comment: The `eregi` function has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and I would not recommend using it again. Also, this question has already been answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374881/how-to-change-phps-eregi-to-preg-match/1374904#1374904. Please check that answer.

Comment: i assume you didn't write that but copied it from somewhere, you need to makes sure the source of any code is up to date.

Comment: sorry i am learning php, i find it easier to copy from other sources and then figure out what makes them work, but yes this has been a trouble that a lot of sources are outdated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right way to validate email in PHP is using the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function with the constant `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

This will return `true` if the submitted email is well shaped, otherwise it will return `false`. You can read more about filters at the [Filter Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php).