# Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated

Tags: php

This is what I get when I try out the contact form on my website:  Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/content/04/11965204/html/horizon/One/contact.php on line 9
 Message sent!

Here is my code:  Please help - thanks

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

$email = $_POST['email'];

//$error[] = preg_match('/\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i', $_POST

['email']) ? '' : 'INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS';

if(!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*" ."@"."([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+"."\\.[a-z]
{2,}"."$",$email )){
    $error.="Invalid email address entered";
    $errors=1;
}

if($errors==1) echo $error;
else{
    $values = array ('name','email','message');
    $required = array('name','email','message');
    $your_email = "horizon.electronics.recyclers@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "New Message: ".$_POST['subject'];
    $email_content = "new message:\n";

    foreach($values as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($value,$required)){
            if ($key != 'subject' && $key != 'company') {
                if( empty($_POST[$value]) ) { echo 'PLEASE FILL IN REQUIRED FIELDS'; exit; }
            }
            $email_content .= $value.': '.$_POST[$value]."\n";
        }
    }

    if(@mail($your_email,$email_subject,$email_content)) {
        echo 'Message sent!'; 
    } else {
        echo 'ERROR!';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Use `preg_match()` instead. Which has been commented out in your code for some reason or another.

Comment: I like how the PHP manual says `eregi()` is deprecated _but doesn't say what the replacement is_

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change PHP's eregi to preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374881/how-to-change-phps-eregi-to-preg-match)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php => *"Tip 
eregi() is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. `preg_match()` with the i (PCRE_CASELESS) modifier is the suggested alternative."* @Bojangles

Comment: It's there, but it's half a screen below the fold, and it's a tip. Not even a warning. Why isn't the Big Red Box saying what the error is? Typical PHP

Answer (score 2):

In PHP 5.3+, `ereg` and `eregi` functions are deprecated. To replace

```
eregi('pattern', $string, $matches)
```

use

```
preg_match('/pattern/i', $string, $matches)
```

(the trailing `i` in the first argument means ignorecase and corresponds to the `i` in `eregi` - just skip in case of replacing `ereg` call).

But be aware of differences between the new and old patterns! [This page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) lists the main differences, but for more complicated regular expressions you have to look in more detail at the differences between [POSIX regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) (supported by the old ereg/eregi/split functions etc.) and the [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

However in your case, there's no need to worry and just do the replacement sketched above.

Comment: @user3142811 If this answers your question, just tick the mark to the left of the post to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Deprecation is a status applied to a computer software feature,
> characteristic, or practice indicating it should be avoided, typically
> because of it being superseded.

[`eregi()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is deprecated as of PHP 5.3, use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I replaced it with

Comment: It is good!) Hope now you will know for the future how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the deprecated [`eregi()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) function or [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) to validate an email address, you're best to use [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and it **uses a lot LESS code**.

Example and an alternative:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Thank you. Your email is valid.";
  // The email address is valid
} else {

echo "INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS";
  // The email address is not valid
}
```

Or  by using an inverted method: `!filter_var`

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  echo "INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Your email is valid.";
  }
```