# change PHP's eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, wamp

I dont know how to fixe this error

```
 Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '[' in
```

my code is

```
while(list($k,$v)=each($con2)) {
    $patt="($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*$this->block_end_delim(.*)";
    if (eregi($patt,$v,$res)) {
```

I want to update php version of eregi to preg_match and I tru this

```
while(list($k,$v)=each($con2)) {
    $patt="($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*$this->block_end_delim(.*)";
    if ( preg_match($patt,$v,$res)) {
```

Comment: be careful with your comparison operators, spend some time learning the difference between =, == and ===

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this answer preg_match treats the first character as a delimiter
[How to change PHP's eregi to preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374881/how-to-change-phps-eregi-to-preg-match)

Specifically you get the error because preg_match uses '(' as the delimiter and thus ends the pattern after ($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word) and errors on '['

Change the pattern to 
$patt="/($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)[[:blank:]]*$this->block_end_delim(.*)/";

And it should work, Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's go over this regex:

`"($this->block_start_word|$this->block_end_word)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*$this->block_end_delim(.*)"`

I presume you want:

- either the literal string `$this->block_start_word` or `$this->block_end_word`
- followed by 0 or more blankspace characters
- followed by 1 or more alphanumeric characters
- followed by 0 or more blankspaces
- followed by the literal string `$this->block_end_delim`
- until the end of the line

That in mind, how about

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', "r");
while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $exp  = '/';
        $exp .= '(';
        $exp .= '\$this\-\>block_start_word';
        $exp .= '|';
        $exp .= '\$this\-\>block_end_word';
        $exp .= ')';
        $exp .= '\s*'; // Like [[:blank:]]*
        $exp .= '([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)';
        $exp .= '\s*'; // Like [[:blank:]]*
        $exp .= '\$this\-\>block_end_delim';
        $exp .= '(.*)/';
        if(preg_match($exp,$line)) {
                print $line;
        }
}
?>
```

If `$this->block_start_word`, `$this->block_end_word`, and `$this->block_end_delim` are set elsewhere in the PHP script:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', "r");
while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $exp  = '/';
        $exp .= '(';
        $exp .= '$this->block_start_word;
        $exp .= '|';
        $exp .= '$this->block_end_word;
        $exp .= ')';
        $exp .= '\s*'; // Like [[:blank:]]*
        $exp .= '([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)';
        $exp .= '\s*'; // Like [[:blank:]]*
        $exp .= $this->block_end_delim;
        $exp .= '(.*)/';
        if(preg_match($exp,$line)) {
                print $line;
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `preg_match` you should define delimiters and you'd better include `preg_quote` as well:

```
$patt="/(".preg_quote($this->block_start_word)."|".preg_quote($this->block_end_word."))[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*".preg_quote($this->block_end_delim)."(.*)/";
```