# Alternatives to eregi regular expression function input

Tags: php, regex

I apologize to post this question, but I am totally incompetent in regards to regular expressions.

I received some deprecated code, in particular, this snippet:

```
eregi("<MERCHANT>(.*)<\/MERCHANT>", $fcontents, $merchant_id);
eregi("<ORDERID>(.*)<\/ORDERID>", $fcontents, $orderid_id);
eregi("<TXORDER>(.*)<\/TXORDER>", $fcontents, $txorder_id);
eregi("<AMOUNT>(.*)<\/AMOUNT>", $fcontents, $amount);
eregi("<RESULT>(.*)<\/RESULT>", $fcontents, $judge_re);
eregi("<CODE>(.*)<\/CODE>", $fcontents, $error_code);
```

It seems the `eregi()` function is deprecated as of [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php).

The input string is an XML string that's returned through cURL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><DRAWBACKAPI><MERCHANT>10023951776</MERCHANT><ORDERID>1687143935</ORDERID><TXORDER>20141021114751</TXORDER><AMOUNT>0.01</AMOUNT><RESULT>N</RESULT><CODE>不在可信任的IP之内</CODE></DRAWBACKAPI>
```

I searched around StackOverflow and it appears `preg_match()` is the alternative to this deprecated function, but I am totally incompetent in regex to make this work - I appreciate any help.

Comment: `preg_match()` will show you how. And also add a quantifier `?` after `*` to do a shortest possible match `<MERCHANT>(.*?)<\/MERCHANT>`

Comment: `preg_match()` is an alternative, but you should use an XML parser.

Comment: "Perl-style regex patterns always need to be delimited" http://stackoverflow.com/a/1374904/2703418 . Use a `/`, for example, to start and end the string with.

Comment: Would an XML parser be better or would regex suffice? Are there downsides/upsides to either?

Comment: **Use an XML parser..**

Comment: Wow, five years after deprecation…

Comment: @feeela It's what happens when you get old old code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an [XML parser](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string) for this, becuase it's what they're built for.

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><DRAWBACKAPI><MERCHANT>10023951776</MERCHANT><ORDERID>1687143935</ORDERID><TXORDER>20141021114751</TXORDER><AMOUNT>0.01</AMOUNT><RESULT>N</RESULT><CODE>不在可信任的IP之内</CODE></DRAWBACKAPI>
XML;

$objXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$merchant = $objXml->MERCHANT;
$orderid = $objXml->ORDERID;
//...
```

Comment: Thank you hd. I will look into this after I get some sleep.

Comment: You're welcome :) Also, you have an awesome name @theGreenCabbage `:P`

Comment: Thank you HD - worked perfectly: http://puu.sh/cm1Km/9169fbc1e0.png (Didn't bother to indent, but the returned results are all correct).

Comment: Awesome stuff! Great to hear