# php Determine a float variable has two decimal places

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

MySQL data imoprt mongo database.

```
price float(15,2) in mysql, mongo is not float(15,2).
```

I want to Determine a var `$price` have two decimal places.

eg. 100.00 is right, 100 or 100.0 is wrong.

**eg.1**

```
$price = 100.00;
```

`$price` have two decimal, it's right.

**eg.2**

```
$price = 100.0;
```

`$price` have not two decimal, it's wrong.

Comment: The number of decimal places in a floating-point number is really down to formatting for display. Can you explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried the answer I left for you? You did not leave feedback under it, whether it worked for you or not.

Comment: @jingyu Hello, do you want to display any price value with two numbers after decimal point in PHP? Let me know. Maybe i will be able to help you out. Regards

Comment: don't use FLOAT to store prices, floating-point numbers may lose precision and they may produce unexpected results. Better to use DECIMAL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everybody is dancing around the fact that floating point numbers don't have a number of decimal places in their internal representation. i.e. in float 100 == 100.0 == 100.00 == 100.000 and are all represented by the same number, effectively 100 and is stored that way.

The number of decimal places in this example only has a context when the number is represented as a string. In which case any string function that counts the number of digits trailing the decimal point could be used to check.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use Regular Expressions to do these things

```
function validateTwoDecimals($number)
{
   if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/', $number))
     return true;
   else
     return false;
}
```

(Thanks to Fred-ii- for the corrections)

Comment: You shouldn't use `ereg` it's deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php

Comment: I'm not sure if its the correct solution, I think my php is a bit obsolete now :S

Comment: Actually, you're missing the delimiters. Should probably be `preg_match('/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$/'` as per one example http://stackoverflow.com/a/1374920/

Comment: What a shame on me, @Fred-ii-. I totally would vote up your answer if you make it, is really yours :!

Comment: It's fine Leandro, am just here to assist. +1

Comment: I fiddle it and it's fine

Comment: It's only me, or there's something you're not taking in the calculations?
Floating numbers does not have decimal places, it's only matter of rounding up/down, if you round to 2 decimals, you will have at most 2 decimal places, but if you round to 10 decimal places, you might end up with something like 9.0000000001 or 8.9999999999
So first of all, if the SQL is really storing floating values, then the question can not be answered ...

In this case first he have to round to some amount of decimals, and check if that value is correct. but in this case, 100.10 is not a valid output ...

Answer (score 3):

```
number_format($price, $numberOfDecimalDigits) === $price;
```

or

```
strrpos($price, '.') === strlen($price) - 1 - $numberOfDecimalDigits;
```

Trivia: `$price` should not be called a "float variable". This is a string that happens to represent a float value. `100.00` as a float has zero decimal digits, and `100.00 === 100` as float :

```
$price = 100.00;
echo $price; // output: 100
$price2 = (float)100;
echo $price === $price2; // ouput: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, the number will need to be wrapped in quotes.

With the many scripts I've tested, using `$price = 100.00;` without quotes did not work, while `$price = 100.10;` did, so this is as best as it gets.

```
<?php 
$number = '100.00';
echo $number.'<br>';
$count = explode('.',$number);

echo 'The number of digits after the decimal point is: ' . strlen($count[1]);

if(strlen($count[1]) == 2){
echo "<br>";
echo "There is 2 decimal points.";
}

else{
echo "<br>";
echo "There is not 2 decimal points.";
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, I always tried with 123.45 and double quotes.

Comment: @Leandro Thanks Leandro. It took me a while, but I managed to get it working. I hope the OP isn't relying on **not** using quotes around the number, otherwise using `.00` will not work without quotes.

Comment: Passing in a price of 100.00.00 will also pass via this code. You should include a check to ensure that the size of the array after exploding is 2.

Answer (score 1):

After you format the value, you can check with simply splitting the value as string into 2 parts, for example with explode ...

```
$ex=explode('.',$in,2); if (strlen($ex[1])==2) 
{
 // true
}
else
{
 // false
}
```

But again, as i've commented already, if you really have floating input, this is just not a reliable way, as floating numbers are without set decimal places, even if they appears so because of the rounding at the float=>string conversion

What you can do, if you really have floating numbers and wish to have xxx.yy format numbers:

1) convert float to string using round($x,2), so it will round to 2 decimal places.
2) explode the number as i've described, *and* do the following:

```
while (strlen($ex[1]<2)) {$ex[1].='0';}
$number=implode('.',$ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following function for that:

```
function isFloatWith2Decimals($number) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/^(?:[1-9]{1}\d*|0)\.\d{2}$/', $number);
}
```

This will also check if you have only one leading 0 so number like `010.23` won't be considered as valid whereas number like `0.23` will.

And if you don't care about leading 0 you could use simpler method:

```
function isFloatWith2Decimals($number) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/^\d+\.\d{2}$/', $number);
}
```

Of course numbers need to be passed as string - if you pass `100.00` won't be considered as true, whereas `'100.00'` will